# MySQL DATE_ADD() Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a date column based on an existing date column by adding days/weeks/months to the existing date

```
update Form_1 set `DateP1`= DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL `P1` week) where 
`id`=1;
```

This works perfectly, however what I am trying to achieve is something like this which does not seem to work

```
update Form_1 set `DateP1`= DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL `P1` `TimeType`) where 
`id`=1;
```

Here, the `TimeType` is another column in my table and contains values like day, week, month... basically the time information. I want to be able to pull value from the column dynamically instead of

```
DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL `P1` week)
```

where week is static. Is there a way to achieve this. I am OK with using any other alternate method as long as I can dynamically pull the values from the TimeType table.

Comment: Can't you use `CASE` expression there to check the value of your column and then use `DATE_ADD()` based on the value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression

```
update Form_1 
set `DateP1`= CASE `TimeType`
                   WHEN 'day' THEN DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL `P1` day)
                   WHEN 'week' THEN DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL `P1` week)
                   ...
              END
WHERE `id`=1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sami. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.